# Fade In / Out RBGA Background colors - Jquery Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

Is it possible to fade in a RGBA background color via a JS script?
I basically would like to do something pretty much exactly like this - (http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/AtzpB), but i want to fade in a background via function rather than hover?

Comment: You can keep the CSS transition, which is smooth and nice. Instead of using `:hover`, trigger the transition by toggling a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert the `:hover` into a class instead:

```
.boo.hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Then toggle it using jQuery:

```
$('.boo').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

I forked your example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dIJah. Click on image to toggle.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible with jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). If you want to append the hover event via script:

```
$('#yourDivId').hover(function(){
$(this).animate({ "backgroundColor" : "rgba(1,2,3, .4)"}, 400);
}, function(){
$(this).animate({ "backgroundColor" : "rgba(4,3,2, .1)"}, 400)
});
```

If you want to just animate via script, just remove the `hover` and replace `$(this)` with the element you want to animate.

```
$('#yourDivId').animate({ "backgroundColor" : "rgba(4,3,2, .1)"}, 400)
```

you can also apply one of these [easings](http://easings.net/it) to the animation.